# Unable to run tests on edge using WebDriverManager with Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

My framework is based on Selenium + TestNG and for the binary management we are using Webdriver Manager (Boni garcia).

I'm using MacOS Catalina 10.15.7

I can execute the suite on edge using a third party platform for example Saucelabs but I'm not able to do it locally. When I try to execute the suite locally I get the following error:

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libc++.dylib
> Referenced from: /Users/xxx/.m2/repository/webdriver/edgedriver/mac64/x64/87.0.664.47/msedgedriver
> Reason: image not found
> Nov 25, 2020 11:52:29 AM org.openqa.selenium.os.OsProcess checkForError
> SEVERE: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 134 (Exit value: 134)

In my pom I have this version of web driver manager.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
        <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

And I initialize the driver this way:

```
private void setUpLocalEdge() {
    WebDriverManager.edgedriver().setup();
    driver = new EdgeDriver();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix it. The webdriver manager by Boni Garcia isn't downloading the libc++.dylib file.

You can fix it by downloading the driver manually from the MsEdge website and doing a copy/paste of the file in the specified path given in the error response.